# Chrome Autofill CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, autofill

I successfully changed Chrome's input Autofill styling to transparent (however) this only works as you type into the input field.

If you select one of the autofill options to populate the field then the input color becomes an opaque white and you can't see behind it. I cant the CSS that is doing this either.

Here is a codePen if you want to take a look.
https://codepen.io/jinch/pen/wvmrGGJ?editors=1100

Is there any way to keep this field transparent (at all times)? Any suggestions appreciated.

Cheers.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px white inset;
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee !important;
}
```

Comment: that behavior is useful to users: it helps them know which fields were autofilled by chrome.

Comment: yes but in my particular case I need to style this background to have the input appear differently on both success and fail triggered by some javascript. Keeping the default behavior is not an option.

Comment: it's your box-shadow causing the issue; disabling it made the inputs look the same as the non-autofilled ones

Comment: Thanks Esther - it took me a sec but I realized it was something I did. Appreciate the feed back. Much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
   transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}
```

Just this code should be work.

Comment: Cheers - i discovered that just as you answered. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is interested - that code above works. The issue was I think self introduced into the CSS. Removing the box-shadow style will fix the issue I was experiencing - `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px white inset;`